# Veeam B/up and azure storage

Tags: veeam

We have Veeam on-premises and want to also use Azure blob storage with it. We want to backup data locally and then create a secondary copy in the cloud (Azure) like D2D2C (disk-to-disk-to-cloud). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Veeam can send data to S3-compatible object storage and Azure blob storage using 'Capacity Tier' which is part of your Scale-out Backup Repository (SOBR), which requires an Enterprise license.

Under 'Backup Infrastructure', 'Scale-out Repositories', you can create a new Scale-out Repository and add normal Veeam Backup Repositories that are not set to receive incompatible data types (transaction log backups, configuration backups, etc) as part of your 'Performance Tier'. The Veeam Object Storage Repository becomes part of your 'Capacity Tier'.

Note: As of writing, in Veeam 9.5 U4, you're allowed to have two Scale-out Repositories each with 1 object storage repository and 3 active standard backup repositories in Enterpise edition. Enterprise Plus removes these limitations. 
https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/backup_repository_sobr.html?ver=95u4

You don't need to create a secondary copy job for this, instead all you would do is point your job to the Scale-out Repository, and let it handle the rest. The Scale-out Repository 'Capacity Tier' settings allow you to set how soon data is archived off to the cloud. https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/capacity_tier.html?ver=95u4